# Advanced text highlight settings for eclipse-plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, xtext

Is it possible to change default settings for the background color of highlighted expressions in the code editor?

When I place the cursor on a method, other places the method exists are grey backgrounded. The same background color appears by placing the cursor on a class. How can I change the background color of highlighted methods to red and the background color of highlighted classes to green?

Comment: What editor? Eclipse has dozens of editors. Please explain in much more detail wat you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited the question.

Comment: Which code editor? Eclipse supports lots of programming languages. Are you asking about if there is a setting in the Preferences for the editor? Or how to do this programmatically?

Comment: I want to do this programatically. The code editor supports a self developed programming language which is modeled by xtext.

Comment: I have added the [tag:xtext] tag to the question. I suggest you [edit] the question to make it clear you are developing an Xtext editor and want to add code to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is "Mark Occurrences". In Xtext these are computed by instances of [IOccurrenceComputer](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-eclipse/blob/master/org.eclipse.xtext.ui/src/org/eclipse/xtext/ui/editor/occurrences/IOccurrenceComputer.java). The default implementation is [DefaultOccurrenceComputer](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-eclipse/blob/master/org.eclipse.xtext.ui/src/org/eclipse/xtext/ui/editor/occurrences/DefaultOccurrenceComputer.java). If you replace this instance with your own implementation (inside your module class using Guice) you can return your own [Annotation](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.text/blob/master/org.eclipse.text/src/org/eclipse/jface/text/source/Annotation.java)'s. You can then provide your own extensions to the [annotations extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_editors_annotationTypes.html) from eclipse with colors of your choice.